# Searching for Accepted Closed Answers Breaks Search

Tags: bug, search

The following search returns absolutely nothing:

> isaccepted:yes closed:no
>
> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3Ayes+closed%3Ano

This probably isn't proper behavior.

While I don't like the 'standard' behavior, searching for answers that aren't closed returns a list of questions that are not closed:

> is:answer closed:no
>
> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+closed%3Ano

Ideally, anything involving an answer would take the 'closed' status from the parent question, rather than having a 'flag priority' which returns unexpected results (especially returning no results at all, which is the worst possible behavior if there is no indication of what got broken).

---

For reasons unknown, the advanced search API returns things totally differently.

- [`isaccepted:yes closed:no` returns 5,664,223](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#page=1&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&q=isaccepted%3Ayes%20closed%3Ano&filter=!FSKNZa0lf47PA&site=stackoverflow&run=true) vs. [3 for advanced search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3Ayes+closed%3Ano)
- [`isaccepted:yes` returns 5,897,668](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#page=1&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&q=isaccepted%3Ayes&filter=!FSKNZa0lf47PA&site=stackoverflow&run=true) vs. [3,516,854 for advanced search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3Ayes)

Comment: Actually it returns three results [on the main site](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3Ayes+closed%3Ano)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Weird. All three from the same day too. What are the chances of that? Definitely not expected behavior at any rate...

Comment: Most likely a bug, marking those questions as accepted answers somehow. In general, you're "abusing" the poor search - `isaccepted:yes` is meant only for answers and `closed:no` is meant for questions. No results is actually the expected behavior in my opinion, but that's might be only me.

Comment: It just struck me... if you're looking for non closed questions that got an accepted answer, proper query is [hasaccepted:yes closed:no](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3Ayes+closed%3Ano).

Comment: What I'm actually looking for is answers to non-closed questions that are accepted. I want the search results to return answers. My original query was [this](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+isaccepted%3Ayes+score%3A..3): `is:answer isaccepted:yes score:..3`. If I use your workaround, I can only search for questions with a score less than 3, which could be useful as well I suppose, but really isn't the same thing, is it?

Comment: I see your point now, but it's not a bug - what you said about "anything involving an answer would take the 'closed' status from the parent question" might be a fine feature request.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The fact that the search as-listed only shows 3 questions from the same date in October 2010 indicates that there is something funky going on with that search and it certainly is bugged. The fact that `is:answer` with `closed:no` only returns questions is not a bug and would be a feature request which I will make promptly.

Comment: Not really, this only expose a bug in the database raw data that somehow got messed (e.g. field containing some unexpected value).

Comment: Sorry @Sha, I'm a bit lost. You are saying it is intended behavior for nothing to be returned if the `isaccepted:yes/no` and `closed:yes/no` flags are used together? That doesn't make much sense (since other combinations of answer-only and question-only tags return something). I would definitely label this a bug, though the database issue is likely a separate bug entirely.

Comment: OK, maybe it's on the edge... hopefully dev will pop by and end the confusion. :-)