# is:answer flag in advanced search should only return answers

Tags: feature-request, search

If you [search for `is:answer`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer) you will get a list of answers:

> [image: Search Results with is:answer]

However, if you [search for `is:answer closed:no`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+closed%3Ano) then you get a list of questions:

> [image: Search Results with is:answer closed:no]

### Searches tagged `is:answer` should only return answers.

The `is:answer` flag should take priority, and anything related to the question should be inherited from the parent question (like using `question_id` field for answers in the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers)). This way we could, for instance, [search for accepted answers on open questions that have a score of less than 0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+closed%3Ano+isaccepted%3Ayes+score%3A..0). This currently returns nothing while [removing the question-related `closed:no`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+isaccepted%3Ayes+score%3A..0) will provide us with what we want.

Comment: To play devils advocate by performing this search you've specified that you want only questions _and_ only answers. Why should the answers take priority over the questions?

Comment: because the intend was "all answers in all non-closed questions"

Comment: @ben, thanks for the advocacy. If I want non-closed questions I can [search for `is:question closed:no`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano) and get the desired results. I can do the same if I just [search for `closed:true`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Ano) since only questions can be closed/open. Why would I add `is:answer` if I wanted questions? That makes absolutely no sense, while there are plenty of reasons to want to look at answers to closed questions (which is implied by the type of request).

Comment: Related: [Searching for Accepted Closed Answers Breaks Search](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201970/searching-for-accepted-closed-answers-breaks-search).  It would seem that `is:closed` is the culprit here.  Since there are so heavily related, maybe one need to be a dup of the other so we don't have 2 posts on search problems with `is:closed`?

Comment: @psu that's a bug report related to inconsistent behavior with the isaccepted flag with a question-only flag. It is quite a bit different from this request which goes beyond just fixing the bug and moves to actually allowing people to search like they would expect.

Comment: @jmac yeah, you are right, sorry, I just read both questions and saw the relation.  I hadn't read the comment chain on the other question until after I made that comment.

Comment: @jmac Why did you roolback my edit?

Comment: @gparyani, if you read the comments, this is separate from the (related) bug report I filed. This is requesting an improvement. Why are you unhappy about the rollback?

Comment: @jmac I was just confused, because normally if an edit is incorrect, it gets rejected. But in this case, it was approved and then rolled back.

Comment: Someone else approved it while I was sleeping. I woke up and rolled it back @gpar

Answer (score 2):

I think you've come up with a solution without having the correct problem defined, so you're coming at it from the wrong direction and would likely end up with something that doesn't actually meet the requirement you though it would.

What it appears you're actually after is for a way to search for answers to open questions.

I would make a suggestion that one way to achieve this is for some advanced search options like the following:

`Show questions []` `Show answers [✓]` `show closed posts []` `show open posts [✓]`

We'd probably want all boxes ticked by default, as that way *everything* is included in the results. This way you don't even have to faff around with the correct syntax, you just enter your query and choose if you only want answers or only want questions

(I am aware that if we start down this route then the advanced search could end up with hundreds of options in there, but it's a different option for discussion I think).

Comment: Jon, would you mind explaining what the proper definition of the problem is? You seem to be advocating switching text-based switches to checkbox-based switches without actually changing any behavior. How is `is:answer` any different from a check box with the same behavior? Or `closed:yes` any different from a check box for that? The issue here is not the text-based switches, but rather that the switches don't operate as one would assume they do. Hence the feature-request to change the way they work.