# Answer sorting based on views on question?

Tags: support

Can I sort my answers based on its questions view count? Do i need any privilege to get this?

I want to see my answers sorted based on views as we can do on questions.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com). [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/143652/177004/) will return links to question you have answered, ordered by views of the question. I am not a pro, this could likely be dramatically improved.

Note: This will only tell you how many people viewed the *question*. If you answer a 3 year old question, it will tell you how many views the question got including the three years before you answered. SE has explained that they do not record historical view counts, so there is no way to see how many views a question had at date X currently. As long as you don't answer old questions, you should probably be okay.

Comment: We will able to do this if [the feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201973/187824) suggested by you is implemented. Am I right?

Comment: @hims No it wouldn't. Sorting by views is not supported even if the search results could return answers by views. If my feature was implemented, it should provide a list of your answers with views over X, for instance `views:500 user:me is:answer` (which [currently returns only questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A209637+views%3A100+is%3Aanswer)), but the ability to sort by views wouldn't be supported without a separate request (we can only sort by activity, creation, or score currently).

Comment: Ohh. You are correct. I misunderstood the question. What you said (answers with views over X)  is what I meant to say. #MondayBlues. :)

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible,

You can sort answers by `newest, activity & votes`. no privileges available for such type of sorting.

You can only sort Questions by `view`.

Comment: But how can I know which of my answers would much seen by users.

Comment: This facility only available for questions.

Comment: @SubinJacob: but how would that work?

Comment: I want to make answers for most viewed questions better. How can I do this. Now I have to go all through the answers and find the questions which got a higher number of views.