# Can we make closed:0 and is:answer work together so only answers are returned on open questions?

Tags: bug, search

I'm not sure whether this is a bug or was planned, but I created a filter to return posts that meet the following requirements:

- is:answer - The posts are answers only.
- hasnotice:1 - The posts have a post notice on them
- closed:0 - The questions are not closed.

https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/search?q=hasnotice%3A1+is%3Aanswer+closed%3A0

The problem is that the first two filters work correctly if closed:0 is omitted. I get back answers with a post notice, but if I add closed:0 to try and filter out answers on closed questions, I end up getting questions themselves back in the search results.

It would be helpful if it were possible to return answers that are on open questions, since answers on closed questions are arguably a different matter.

In short, can we make closed:0 and is:answer work together so only answers are returned on open questions?

Comment: Also related to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201973/isanswer-flag-in-advanced-search-should-only-return-answers)